# layoutSubviews and animations

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am experiencing animation problems.

This is my current setup so far

1. I have initialized my objects (UIViews) in the 
   `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` method
2. I adjust and layer the frames of views as well as added subviews in the `- (void)layoutSubviews` method.

When I try to animate the views/subviews, nothing happens. Everything worked well until I moved the layering to the "initWithFrame" method, it works good.

Could somebody explain what the the cause could be and why the layered views in layoutSubviews can't be animated well?

I believe that it might be due to the hierarchy of calling methods, am I right in thinking that?

Code (subclass of UIView):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
(...)
backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
(...)
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
(...)
frame = (CGRect){ 100, 100, 200, 200 };
[backgroundView setFrame:frame];
(...)
[self addSubview:backgroundView];
}

- (void)animate 
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 300);
} completion:^{BOOL f){ 
NSLog(@"w: %f h: %f", backgroundView.frame.size.width, backgroundView.frame.size.height); 
}];
}
```

Tried to call "animate" from subview (by using `[(MyClass *)self.superview animate]`) as well as send notification. 
Always log was

> w: 200 h: 200

Comment: Watch out. `layoutSubviews` can be called many times in the lifetime of your view, and you are adding `backgroundView` again and again each time that happens.

Comment: Your layoutSubviews doesn't call [super layoutSubviews], I had weird behaviour every time I missed this call. Wrapping the rest of the layoutSubviews in UIView animate block should be working. I have this in one of my projects. 
Also, there is no need to have [self addSubview:backroundView] in layoutSubviews. It won't hurt anything, but it doesn't belong there logically. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Arcanfel It doesn't sadly help. backgroundView still doesn't animate/change. I remember I tested it with setFrame even without UIVIew animate block and it didn't change as well. So where logically I should ad subviews?

Comment: I see that I can't just layout these views in method layoutSubviews, which frames I'm changing later.

Comment: I would keep addSubview: in init method

Comment: @Arcanfel Thanks, I've read a little bit about this. layoutSubviews is called by/after addSubview in many cases. This may cause my problem.